# PHP: preg_replace help

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
$string = '[url]http://google.com[/url]';
$bbreplace = array ('/\[url\](.+?)\[\/url\]/');
$bbreplacements = array ('<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>');
$string = preg_replace($bbreplace, $bbreplacements, $string);
print $string;
```

Which creates a url called http://google.com/ that points to

```
mydomain.com/"http://google.com/"
```

instead of

```
http://google.com/
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: *(tipp)* PECL [BBCode Parser](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) and PEAR [HTML_BBCodeParser](http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser)

Comment: I doubt that your example really does what you say it does. The string `mydomain.com` is nowhere to be seen, and the regex engine surely is not going to generate it out of nothing...

Comment: mydomain.com is what shows up when i run it on my machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape the `"` inside `'`.

```
$bbreplacements = array ('<a href="\\1">\\1</a>');
```

(BTW, use a [BBcode parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php).)